# Primality testing for quaternions

Tags: number-theory, quaternions

Let $H(-1,-p) = \mathbb{Q}+\mathbb{Q}i+\mathbb{Q}j+\mathbb{Q}k$ be the quaternion algebra over $\mathbb{Q}$ such that $i^2=-1, j^2=-p$ and the quaternion is ramified exactly at $p$ and $\infty$. $\mathcal{O}=\mathbb{Z}+\mathbb{Z}i+\mathbb{Z}j+\mathbb{Z}k$ is an order of the quaternion. We define an element $a\in \mathcal{O}$ is a prime if $a$ cannot be represent as the product of two non unit elements $b,c$, namely, $a=bc,$ where $b,c\in \mathcal{O}$ and $b$, $c$ are not units. The question is, given an element $ a\in \mathcal{O}$. How to efficiently test its primality?

To our best knowledge, this question is solved when the $\mathcal{O}$ is a Hurwitz order, we have no idea about this question when the quaternion algebra is not Hamilton. There exists a very trivial method. First we compute its norm $N$ and factor it $N=p_1^{e_1},\ldots, p_n^{e_n}$, next list all possible elements in the order with proper norm ,namely the factot of $N$ and test whether it is a factor of $a$. But this method is not efficiently.

Comment: For quaternions the convention is $j^2=-1,$ isn't it?

Comment: @Bumblebee [(generalized) quaternion algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion_algebra).

Comment: The quaternions is not commutative, so it is not a field. I want to test its primality in an order. As for the convention of quaternion,  I am not sure. Anyway, there are isomorphic.

Comment: @JonathanZ The OP used the notation $\mathcal{O}$ which strongly suggests that they want to study primeness in the order $\Bbb{Z}$-spanned by the four generators (even before the edit). True, the question is  rather lacking of [context and related stuff we want to see in questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/35391/11619), and the asker should clarify anyway. As well as describe what they know about the question.

Comment: Don't say that the quaternions haven't a field structure ! The quaternions are a *skew* field !

Comment: @Jirki Lahtonen : You are right, it is a question about "Lipschitz quaternions" with a clear answer about primality [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurwitz_quaternion)

Comment: @ Jean Marie
 You are right, but I still have no idea about this question when order is not a Hurwitz order. Does the result of Hurwitz order factorization still hold?

Comment: @matthew: It is better to refine your question with more details. Otherwise, there is a danger that it might get closed by the policeman around.